# AVG() in Pig Error

Tags: apache-pig

My code:

```
table = load '/tmp/baseball/Salaries.csv' using PigStorage(',') AS (yearID,teamID,lgID,playerID,salary);
table2 = load '/tmp/baseball/Fielding.csv' using PigStorage(',') AS      (playerID,yearID,stint,teamID,lgID,Pos,G,GS,InnOuts,PO,A,E,DP,PB,WP,SB,CS,ZR);
combined_table = JOIN table by (yearID,playerID),table2 by (yearID,playerID);
combined_table_grped = GROUP combined_table BY Pos;
avg = FOREACH combined_table_grped GENERATE     combined_table.Pos,AVG(combined_table.salary);
dump avg;
```

but I got this:

```
<file 5_avg_salary_2.pig, line 5, column 57> Multiple matching functions for org.apache.pig.builtin.AVG with input schema: ({{(bytearray)}}, {{(double)}}). Please use an explicit cast.
```

I'm in general pretty confused about when AVG can be used. Theoretically my code should work...Can someone help me? Thanks!!!

Comment: It is good practice for the field names in the `AS` part of the load statement to have data types, e.g. `AS (yearID:chararray, ..., salary:double)`. This helps Pig chose the right UDF (i.e. the one matching the types).

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with field type mismatch. Try to initiallize the colomn type to double . As the default type will be bytearray.you can also use explicit cast to store the result in double as the default bytearray will throw the error as shown in question.

Comment: PIG field default is bytearray and not chararray. Refer https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/basic.html#Schemas